# Find the difference equation given the general solution $y(k) = c_{1}5^{k} + c_{2}(-5)^{k} + c_{3}6^{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations, homogeneous-equation

Given that $y(k) = c_{1}5^{k} + c_{2}(-5)^{k} + c_{3}6^{k}$, is the general solution to a difference equation, how do you work backwards to find the difference equation?

Comment: You should be able to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial and work from there.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you are looking not for a third order difference equation but for a third order linear recurrence relationship $y_{k+3}=Ay_{k+2}+By_{k+1}+Cy_{k}$ ?

Comment: Light hint: the characteristic polynomial is $\,(t-5)(t+5)(t-6)\,$. Heavy hint: write the recurrence for three consecutive terms, then eliminate the powers between the three equations.